# Dropdown List From Database Using PHP In HTML

Tags: php, html

I would like to create a dropdown list from a database using PHP in my HTML code, however the list is returning Array() instead of the values:

```
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-plus-sign scolor"></i> Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" >

    <li><a>
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT USER FROM table";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                $ArrayUSER = array();
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $USER = $row["USER"];
                    $ArrayUSER[] = $USER ;
                    }
                    print_r($ArrayUSER);

                } else {
                    echo "USER: 0 ";
                }
            ?>
    </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: you're using the wrong variable. print $USER and you'll see magic happen

Comment: I've been playing around with code, I've forgot to add $ArrayUSER[] = $USER; but this still doesn't work

Comment: Fred, thank you for that, but it only prints the last USER, do I need a For loop perhaps?

Comment: you're welcome. TBH, I don't even think you need `$ArrayUSER = array();` etc. just use a regular `while` loop and echo the `$row`.

Comment: It prints all USERS in the same line, meaning I cannot select a user from the dropdown

Comment: that's an easy one... concatenate `<br>`'s

Comment: It prints all USERS in the same line, meaning I cannot select a user from the dropdown

Comment: you have been given answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you the data - add each new user to the array, instead of saving in into $USER, then print the array.

```
$ArrayUSER = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $ArrayUSER[] = $row["USER"];
     }
     print_r($ArrayUSER);
} else {
    echo "USER: 0 ";
}
```

For a formatted list, you need to put the HTML in the loop, though, and you don't need an array.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo '<li><a>' . $row["USER"] . '</a></li>';
     }
} else {
    echo "USER: 0 ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
<?php
            $sql = "SELECT USER FROM table";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            $ArrayUSER = array();
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $USER = $row["USER"];

                echo "<li><a>" .$USER."</a></li>";} 
            }
```

Comment: isn't that what they have now?

Comment: No i have changed the variable from $ArrayUSER to $USER..  plus the placing of } for while loop....

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your answer to make it print `<li>` with every row from the data base like this

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" >
<?php
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT USER FROM table");
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $USER = $row["USER"];
     echo '<a><li>'.$USER.'</li></a>';
      }
?>
</ul>
```

this will make every database row in a different `<li>`